# printing union variable - odd behaviour

Tags: c, printf, unions, type-punning

```
#include <stdio.h>

union p{
    int x;
    float y;
};

int main()
{
    union p p;
    p.x = 10; 
    printf("%f\n", p.y);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 0.000000

When I am trying to compile above programs, it is not showing any warnings,
even in the main function. Why is `printf` not printing value `10.00000`?

I have read some related questions on *stackoverflow* which explains behavior of `printf` while printing integer without typecasting with float specifier, but i think here it is a different case. I am printing float number with float specifier. It should print the proper value. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Because memory representation of an int and a float is different (check with your debugger and you'll see). Moreover writing p.x and accessing p.y is undefined behavior...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti; `accessing p.y is undefined behavior`: No. Not in this case.

Comment: @haccks AFAIK it's not if `int` and `float` have same size (actually if they're _compatible types_) but it's not required they are (and here it's unknown because it depends on environment). If I'm not wrong...

Answer (score 5):

This is due to a fact that both `int` and `float` objects have different binary representations. Assuming 32-bit `int` and `float`, little-endian and IEEE-754 representation, you have binary pattern as:

```
0000 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

that is (in context of floating number) very small number, which has printed value as `0.000000` using `%f` format specifier (one may say that is rounded by `printf`). You might try with `%e` f.s., which results into another output:

```
1.401298e-44
```

C99 introduced `%a` f.s., which represents floating-number exactly as it's stored, namely as 2-base floating-point number (i.e. with mantissa and exponent):

```
0x1.4p-146
```

Answer (score 4):

You put 10 integer, into x.
if you write p.x = 1092616192 instead of p.x = 10 you will see what happens
also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

10 is not equal to 10.f in memory.

Comment: That's assuming `int` is 4 bytes, which may not be the case

Comment: ...and if not it'll lead to UB.

Comment: if you want to be pedantic there is no warranty float will have 4 bytes as well. However all common architectures for the moment have int and float 4 bytes long. BTW even better link to see 4 bytes float layout: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @dev_null Over a billion embedded processors are made each year (2014) where C is very popular.  100s of millions of these processors are 16-bit or even 8-bit.  Many such compilers there use 16-bit `int`.  So certainly not all common architectures in 2014 have 4 byte `int`.

Answer (score 3):

*int* and *float* having different binary representations, if you tried printing in scientific format `%e` you would see the following value for `p.f`:

> 1.401298e-44

so assuming [IEEE 754 single precision float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and `4` bytes *int*, let's try a [float convertor](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to see what a valid hex value would be for let's say the value `40` in *IEEE 754* format.

Plugging in `40` into the convertor gives hex value:

> 0x42200000

if we assign this value to `p.x`:

```
p.x = 0x42200000;
```

you will see the value `40` back out when you print `p.y`, [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb1e9fbece53bfe1).

This is always a debate about whether type punning through a union is undefined behavior, as far as I understand it is not and in practice compilers explicitly support this type of type punning, here is [the gcc reference explaining its support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning).